# CMake is converting an absolute path to relative when I use it as a library path

Tags: cmake

I am trying to write CMake code to include a library in my Visual Studio 2013 application. The library lives in a different path depending on whether I am building for 32 or 64 bits. So i write this:

```
if(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
    set(MY_LIBRARY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/foo/x64/mylib.lib")
elseif(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 4)
    set(MY_LIBRARY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/foo/mylib.lib")
endif()

MESSAGE(STATUS "MY_LIBRARY is ${MY_LIBRARY}")

target_link_libraries(
    myapp
    otherlibs
    ${MY_LIBRARY}
)
```

When I display the value of `MY_LIBRARY` in the CMake file, it displays the correct, absolute path but when I open the resulting Visual Studio project file and examine the linker settings, the path has been converted to a relative one.

What's the heck is going on ?

Comment: Is that a problem? cmake generated solution/project files are not supposed to be portable - you should regenerate them on each machine you want to build on. As such, relative paths shouldn't be an issue surely?

Comment: If it is proving to be a problem for you might find this helps: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/policy/CMP0015.html

Comment: it would be perfectly fine if the relative path was correct but it's not - it's also wrong.

Comment: You haven't given any details on how the relative path is incorrect, and how/where? That would help! That said, have you tried using [`find_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_library.html) with the `PATHS` option? That is the recommended way to link a library, and may well solve your issue

Comment: I figured out how to fix it but I'm still not sure why the relative path appears.  I had a typo in the explicit portion so the generated path did not exist. I had for example `"${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/foo/x64/mylib.lib"` when it was actually `"${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/example/foo/x64/mylib.lib"`

Comment: Good to hear! Perhaps consider deleting the question, as it is just due to a typo in your cofde

Comment: In fact, had you used `find_library`, you would have picked up your problem much quicker, because cmake would have been unable to find the library. Perhaps a note for the future - favour `find_library` rather than an explicit path to `target_link_libraries`

Comment: Good idea Steve (to delete the question) but I'm still surprised an invalid value results in a relative path - I would have expected it to propagate through to the Visual Studio Linker settings as an invalid path.

Comment: `find_library` is new to me - I'll take a look - thank you.